# Remove a node from linked list if (condition)

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

My linked list is build up from structs with 4 integers. 
Whenever the integer ttl is below 1 the node should be deleted from my list. 
The code I have at the moment works in some cases, namely only when the node to delete is at the head of the list.

```
typedef struct _ttl_t {
    int x;
    int y;
    int value;
    int ttl;
    struct ttl *next;
} ttl_t;



ttl_t *remove_ttl (ttl_t *head) { // ’r’ command
    if (head==NULL){
        return head;
    }
    else {
        ttl_t *curr=head;
        while (curr){
            if (curr->ttl<1){
                head=curr->next;
                free(curr);
            }
            curr=curr->next;
        } 
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: You need to show a [mcve]. Also tell us which cased works and which don't. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: If you have more than one element to remove from your linked list, `head` is set twice to different values. So at least one is lost.

Comment: You need to keep track of the previous entry when you walk the list. When you find the entry to delete, update head if previous is null, otherwise update previous->next  to point to curr->next;

Comment: Indeed, you always update head, even when you are in the middle of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the structure declaration in the typedef

```
typedef struct _ttl_t {
    int x;
    int y;
    int value;
    int ttl;
    struct ttl *next;
} ttl_t;
```

is incorrect. `struct _ttl_t` and `struct ttl` are two different types. I think you mean

```
typedef struct _ttl_t {
    int x;
    int y;
    int value;
    int ttl;
    struct _ttl_t *next;
} ttl_t;
```

This loop

```
    while (curr){
        if (curr->ttl<1){
            head=curr->next;
            free(curr);
        }
        curr=curr->next;
    }
```

is also incorrect because if a node has the data member `ttl` less than 1 the head node is changed though its own data member `ttl` can be greater than or equal to 1.

The function can be defined simpler if to pass the head node by reference through pointer.

For example

```
void remove_ttl( ttl_t **head ) 
{
    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        if ( ( *head )->ttl < 1 )
        {
            ttl_t *tmp = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            free( tmp );
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
}
```